# What is this plant and how should it be taken care of?

Tags: identification

One of the kids planted a seed in school and this plant grew from it. It’s growing at a pretty fast rate and I’m wondering why it’s growing so tall so quickly when it’s not very strong.

I’m not sure if I should be trimming it shorter to keep it from getting too tall and falling over or maybe it’s some sort of climber.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: climbing bean plant] | [image: climbing bean plant] |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a climbing bean. Its habit is to stretch up to find something to climb on, and it will continue zooming upwards until it maybe hits your door handle and then tie onto it. Best place for it is outside with a tall stick to keep it company.